# Maven: how to globally override outputDirectory for maven-war-plugin

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, war

Is it possible to configure `<outputDirectory>/path/to/tomcat/webapps/</outputDirectory>` in `~/.m2/settings.xml` so that every maven project using `maven-war-plugin` will have this property set by default?

Profiles section of my **settings.xml** (this does not work):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>localhost</id>            
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <directory>/tomcat/webapps</directory>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>/tomcat/webapps</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
<profiles>
```

I want all `war` files to be put in a single `/webapps` directory when running `mvn package` for every project.

It must be done without modifying project's `pom.xml`.

Comment: It looks like you would like to make a deploy to tomcat for such purposes you should look for tomcat-maven-plugin which offers appropriate goals to handle deployment...

Comment: Good! But how to set it globally anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest a different approach. Use the [resources:copy-resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html) goal and bind this to the `package` phase. Trying to solve this in the settings.xml is possible, but requires much more changes inside your pom too and will probably be harder to understand.